# Cumulative sum matlab for loop

Tags: matlab, cumsum, accumarray

I am trying to cumulatively sum consecutive hours(variables 'hrs') between hurricane observations for all observations in a particular storm and among multiple storms in order to determine the duration of the storm. This is what I have:

```
stormid = [188, 188, 288, 288, 288, 388, 488, 488, 588...] %numbers represent a unique 
% code identifying a particular storm (i.e. 188= 1st storm of 1988)

hrs = [0,6,0,6,6,0,0,6,0...] %hours between observations in each storm
% where 0 indicates the start of a storm (this corresponds with the stormid above)
```

My goal is to sum the hrs for each storm id, so I thought using accumarray would work, but it did not. Here is what I tried.

```
duration= accumarray(stormid, hrs, []);
```

Then I also tried cumsum, but I was unable to figure out how to only use cumsum when storm ids are the same.

If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this neatly. `accumarray` can only be used with a function that returns scalars, not vectors, so it can't be used together with `cumsum`. Can you just loop through`stormid` and sum `hrs` manually as you go, starting over each time you find a new id number?

Comment: Well what does the error message for `duration= accumarray(stormid, hrs, []);` say? `Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each`  **row** `in SUBS, or a scalar.`. You could possibly solve this problem of transposing if you just read the second example of `doc accumarray`.

Comment: As a sidenote: As your stormIDs are not continuous, instead of using `accumarray` with a column vector, you should use `sparse`, which can also sum the values, but will save you some memory (or you could convert the IDs in a prepocessing step using `unique`).

Comment: @knedlsepp- there was no error message, the result just gave me a 3105x1 vector when I was expecting a 283 x 1 vector (the number of storms in the dataset) and output that didn't make sense. Based upon what you all have advised though, accumarray won't work. Thanks for the advice, I'll try out your suggestions.

Comment: @knedlsepp: my data is actually arranged in columns, not rows, I just wrote that for the sake of convenience

Comment: @runnere127: Actually your accumarray command **is working** if your data is given in columns and is exactly what you want. The entry `duration(188)` will be the sum of all the stormid `188`. The data in between will be lots of zeros. If you don't want these odd ID numbers, you will have to generate some sane ones by applying `[C,ia,ic] = unique(stormid)` and applying accumarray to `ic`. You can use `ia`, `ic` and `C` afterwards to get the original IDs.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

Edit: I don't have enough points to comment so I just modified the suggested code here. (Am I correct in assuming that the error occurs because duration isn't wide enough?)

```
clear duration
unique_storm_id = unique(stormid);
duration = zeros(length(unique_storm_id),length(hrs));
for k = 1:length(unique_storm_id)
    duration{k} = cumsum(hrs(stormid == unique_storm_id));
end
```

Then you can access the duration for storm id = j using

```
index = find(unique_storm_id == j);
duration{index}
```

Comment: I tried your above code but I received an error message saying that
    "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

Comment: What is the error message and the line where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uni_id = unique(stormid);
cumdur = arrayfun(@(x) cumsum(hrs(stormid == x)), uni_id, 'uni', false);
```

The result, `cumdur`, is a cell array of `cumsum` results applied to `hrs` denoted by consecutive (unique) `stormid`'s.